# MySQL 5.6 Online DDL lead to to much table-metadata-locks when I just add index

Tags: mysql, index, mysql-5.6, alter-table, ddl

It's normal that table-metadata-lock shows up for **a short time** when `ALTER TABLE t add index ...` starts and ends. But I have encountered all DML operations blocked in *Waiting for table metadata lock*, and I'm sure there is no long sql statement running before adding index.

What's more confused is that I saw the ALTER statement *copying to tmp table* in processlist. According to official docs [innodb-create-index-overview](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html), `INPLACE` method should be taken by default, right? ( I just add one secondary index and delete one).

Also I checked `information_schema.innodb_trx` to see whether uncommitted transactions exist. No.

Can someone could explain why this happens for me?

By the way, my (alter) table **t1** has triggers on it. And there's trigger on other table **t2** to update **t1**. Thought I know it's ugly ·_·

**show processlist** after `alter table t1 add key idx_c1_c2(c1,c2), drop key idx_c2`：
[image]

Comment: Waiting for metadata lock is entirely expected while an `ALTER TABLE` is in progress that is doing a copy to temp table... the table is locked while the copy operation is happening.  So the only question here is why this change isn't happening `INPLACE`.

Answer (score 1):

There are good reasons `ALGORITHM=INPLACE` may not be used and switches to `ALGORITHM=COPY`.

## REASON #1

In the [link you gave in the question](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html), there is a chart that shows the following:

- Adding a FULLTEXT index trigger a table copy is not supported for online operation
- Many operations can revert to copy because it says in the notes `Although ALGORITHM=INPLACE is allowed, the data is reorganized substantially, so it is still an expensive operation.`

Some online DDL may still lock and copy because of an index's interaction. Don't forget that each BTREE entry in a secondary index has a hook back to the primary key. Adding a new secondary index may induce row level locks and index locks.

## REASON #2

According the [limitations page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-limitations.html) : `InnoDB tables created before MySQL 5.6 do not support ALTER TABLE ... ALGORITHM=INPLACE for tables that include temporal columns (DATE, DATETIME or TIMESTAMP) and have not been rebuilt using ALTER TABLE ... ALGORITHM=COPY.`

I am sure there are other reasons that can be researched an discussed along these lines.

Comment: After using `algorithm=inplace` to force INPLACE method, the warnings:

    | Level | Code | Message                                                                                            |
    | Note  | 1880 | TIME/TIMESTAMP/DATETIME columns of old format have been upgraded to the new format.                |
    | Error | 1846 | ALGORITHM=INPLACE is not supported. Reason: Cannot change column type INPLACE. Try ALGORITHM=COPY. |

 
My mysql version is *5.6.16-log*. [This chapter](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html) seems to explain clearly.